# Software center says: "check your internet connection" but I do have a connection

Tags: wireless, software-center

I am running ubuntu 14.04 on an Acer aspire netbook all was going well until the latest updates. Now my wireless connection is very unstable and I have just gone to download K3b writing software from the ubuntu software centre and i keep getting an error saying

```
Failed to download package files
 check your internet connection

Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libq/libqapt/libqapt2_2.1.70-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libq/libqapt/libqapt2-runtime_2.1.70-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libq/libqapt/qapt-batch_2.1.70-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
```

I clearly have an internet connection 
thanks in advance

Comment: Try doing updating your package lists, the 404 means it looked but couldn't find those files.

Answer (score 0):

A **404** error tells you that the server was reached but doesn't have the requested file.

For the first line you showed us there is

```
http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libq/libqapt/libqapt2_2.1.70-0ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
```

but not the

```
libqapt2_2.1.70-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb
```

your system was requesting.

Those situations are usually solved by updating the local *apt* database. Open a terminal window and type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It will not hurt to get the actual updates too:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Afterwards you should be able to install any software you want from the Software Center or via command line.